# Nodejs Run code at exactly time once

Tags: node.js

I want to run my process at specific time but just one time. 
Should I use cron job, execute then stop job or use setTimeout ? Which 's better ?

**Update :**
I found it in node-cron module. I think it's better than using setTimeout.

Another example with Date

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var job = new CronJob(new Date(), function(){
 //runs once at the specified date.
}, function () {
 // This function is executed when the job stops
},
true /* Start the job right now */,
timeZone /* Time zone of this job. */
```

);

Answer (score 8):

Check out [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-schedule) package. According to the docs, you can schedule a function at an exact date.

This is the docs [example](https://github.com/mattpat/node-schedule#date-based-scheduling) of scheduling an event at 5:30am on December 21, 2012...

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');
var date = new Date(2012, 11, 21, 5, 30, 0);

var j = schedule.scheduleJob(date, function(){
  console.log('The world is going to end today.');
});
```

If need be, you can cancel a job as well

```
j.cancel();
```

Comment: Note that job will run, when its due date is in the past, at the time the job is scheduled.

Answer (score 5):

Try this with cron if not work try with node-cron.

```js
const cron = require('node-cron');
const moment = require('moment');

const todayMoment = moment().format();
const today = new Date();

function formatDate(date) {
/* take care of the values:
   second: 0-59 same for javascript
   minute: 0-59 same for javascript
   hour: 0-23 same for javascript
   day of month: 1-31 same for javascript
   month: 1-12 (or names) is not the same for javascript 0-11
   day of week: 0-7 (or names, 0 or 7 are sunday) same for javascript
   */
  return `${date.getSeconds()} ${date.getMinutes() + 1} ${date.getHours()} ${date.getDate()} ${date.getMonth() + 1} ${date.getDay()}`;
}

function formatDateMoment(momentDate) {
  const date = new Date(momentDate);

  return `${date.getSeconds()} ${date.getMinutes() + 1} ${date.getHours()} ${date.getDate()} ${date.getMonth() + 1} ${date.getDay()}`;
  // or return moment(momentDate).format('ss mm HH DD MM dddd');
}

function runJob(data) {
  // or                     formatDateMoment
  const job = cron.schedule(formatDate(data), () => {
    doSomething();
  });

  function doSomething() {
    // my code

    // stop task or job
    job.stop();
  }
}
//    todayMoment
runJob(today);
```

Comment: In the `formatDate()` function don't add `1` to minutes since its the same as that of js

Answer (score 4):

It's been over 6 years since the question was posted, but I hope someone finds this answer useful. Cron jobs weren't created to be run once; they instead run at specified intervals. I can't think of a situation where you'll ever need to run a cron job once, but should you find that situation, I hope the code snippet below helps:

```
const cron = require('node-cron');
const EventEmitter = require('events');
const event = new EventEmitter();

// Make your callback function asynchronous so that you can use await
async function doSomething() {
    console.log('Doing something...');
}

const task = cron.schedule('0 1 * * * *', async () => {
    console.log('Running a task every minute');
    await doSomething();
    event.emit('JOB COMPLETED');
});

// Listen to when a 'JOB COMPLETED' event is emitted and stop the task
event.on('JOB COMPLETED', () => {
    console.log('Job done!');
    task.stop();
});
```

Comment: We use cron jobs on our serverless functions and run them once.  As an example,   we need to schedule a cron trigger once at a future date to send an email or notification.   The cron expression is scheduled for 3 says from now.  After the function is run, the cron trigger is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

### Without different scheduler or Node Events

The person who asked the question updated the question with a solution that is straightforward, eliminating the need for a different scheduler or Node Events.

Just in case the update section in the question is hard to understand, here is an explanation.

---

While using the `cron` package, you can either use a cron syntax or use a `Date` object for the first argument.

**If you want the cron job to run exactly once, use a `Date` object for the first parameter.**

The code example below shows how to create a job that runs exactly one time 10 seconds after it is initialized.

```
const CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;

const SECONDS_TO_WAIT = 10;

const dateToRunCode = new Date(Date.now() + SECONDS_TO_WAIT);

new CronJob(
  dateToRunCode, 
  function(){
    console.log("This code will run once.");
  },
  true /* To start the job right now, default is false */,
);
```