# Dynamic cron parameters _ Node Js

Tags: node.js, cron

I have a script that send an email to specific customer but what I'm trying to do is to fire that email in a given time and date .. so the solution is to use [`cron module`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) like below and changing the parameters with what I want

```
 cron.schedule("* * * * * " , function(){
    }
```

the problem that I want to modify those parameters with varibales which contains a result for a specific calculation! like this below

```
const X = 234;// this values will change everyday automatically
cron.schedule("X * * * * " , function(){
    }
```

so is it possible to do something like that or is there a better solution that allows me to modify cron parameters

the solution that I tried but nothing is working  is below :

```
 const x = 40;// 40 seconds
  cron.schedule(`${x} * * * *`, function(){
 }
```

Best Regards,

Comment: You cannot schedule just once and pass variable argument. You've to reschedule it or save that number in somewhere and restart the app which will reread that value and schedule cron.

Comment: Simply save to table jobs the stuff need to do and put cron script to run every minute which will check jobs table and will run what is scheduled by time. Example table: `jobs [id, runAt, method, arguments, done]`, cron will run and will take jobs which is not `done` and `runAt` is less than now, will run `method` and pass `arguments` to it and after finishing it will set `done=true`

Comment: @num8er that's alot of thing to do haha but ok thanks , so you mean that when creating the event that will sent to the customer I must create also a table containing `jobs : array` and also a script that will check that ` job table` until the `done = true` ? there isn't a better solution? do you have an exemple to follow ?

Comment: `I must create also a table ` insert to already existing table `jobs` (it must exists always). `there isn't a better solution? do you have an exemple to follow ?`  - that's enough simple to achieve: 1 insert to table, 1 method that will run by cron and get jobs from table and execute.

Comment: I give db table example since Your app may crash and when it recover it has to run that jobs. But if You don't care about it You can simply use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule  which will create job in memory and will run it when You require it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nodejs Run code at exactly time once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154702/nodejs-run-code-at-exactly-time-once)

Comment: thank you but is `cron` better than `node-schedule` module ?

Comment: cron is for recurrent tasks, node-schedule is for scheduling unique task

Comment: Ok thank you could it possible to post it as answer so I accept it ?  the `jobs table`

Comment: I’ll not write it as an answer, it’s pretty obvious thing (: write it Yourself and accept it

Comment: Thank you have a nice evening :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many Thanks to num8er ,

the only solution for my problem is

> Simply save to table `jobs` the stuff need to do and put cron script to run every minute which will check `jobs table` and will run what is scheduled by time. Example `table: jobs [id, runAt, method, arguments, done]`, cron will run and will take jobs which is not done and `runAt`is less than now, will run method and pass arguments to it and after finishing it will set done=true
>
> that's enough simple to achieve: 1 insert to table, 1 method that will run by cron and get jobs from table and execute