# Looking for time based persistent scheduler - node js

Tags: node.js, cron

I have been looking for a time based persistent scheduler. I looked into some applications ([Agenda](https://www.npmjs.com/package/agenda), node-cron, node-schedule). But I couldn't find anything that satisfies my criteria.

So my applications sends out reminders to our customers based on their event timings. I am hesitating to run a regular cronjob because I have to run every 15 mins or so in this case. And for each cronjob, I have to make a database call. I am trying not to use resources unnecessarily.

In addition to that, I am already running a lot of `cronjobs`. But in my case, when the job is completed, I want the cron to get cancelled/finished; not live on memory until the server restart happens.

I tried using the above specified applications by setting exact timestamps (agenda, node-cron, node-schedule). But the cron lives on forever even after the job is completed, and if i restart the server, all the scheduled jobs are cron. So persistence is also an issue I am facing.

My server uses `node js`. If there are any other languages/tools to make this work, I am all ears.

Looking forward to your help.

I tried following this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154702/nodejs-run-code-at-exactly-time-once/66718460#66718460). But this solution is for one predefined event. In my case, the number of reminders to be sent out are dynamic and jobs are to be scheduled on the fly.

Comment: What do you mean by "But the cron lives on forever even after the job is completed,..." - that is the point of cron jobs, isn't it? Running a task e.g. every 15 minutes as long as the server is running.

Comment: @eol But I am not trying to run the cron job to run 15 minutes. I am trying to schedule a job for a particular time. And when the job is completed, I want the cron to get cancelled/finished; not live on memory until the server restart happens.

Comment: Then your statement "because i have to run every 15 mins or so in this case" does not make sense :) But I see what you mean, maybe check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/66718460/3761628

Comment: @eol I looked for the solution earlier you provided. That solution is valid if i have just one reminder to be sent out and kill the cron. In my case, the situation is dynamic, and I have to schedule cron jobs on the go.